# How catkin compile with rosbuild package?

Tags: catkin, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I write the following code in catkin package :

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <pr2_controllers_msgs/JointTrajectoryAction.h>
#include "actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv; 
using namespace std;
```

When I compile, it shows:

```
/home/ira/code/ros_groovy/src/sam_pr2_lab_auto_scene_4/src/pr2_lab_auto_scene_4.cpp:8:56: fatal error: pr2_controllers_msgs/JointTrajectoryAction.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [sam_pr2_lab_auto_scene_4/CMakeFiles/pr2_lab_auto_scene_4.dir/src/pr2_lab_auto_scene_4.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [sam_pr2_lab_auto_scene_4/CMakeFiles/pr2_lab_auto_scene_4.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

I found that pr2_controllers_msgs package is based on rosbuild.

```
ira@ira:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/pr2_controllers/pr2_controllers_msgs$ ls
action  bin  CMakeLists.txt  mainpage.dox  Makefile  manifest.xml  msg  msg_gen  ROS_NOBUILD  src  srv  srv_gen
ira@ira:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/pr2_controllers/pr2_controllers_msgs$
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186315/how-catkin-compile-with-rosbuild-package?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2014-07-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Build your package with rosbuild, too or change your depended package to catkin (which might be impossible as that seem to be a basic package).

Unfortunately, this is the only solution. catkin packages cannot depend on rosbuild packages.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2014-07-13**:
So why we need catkin? Is there any simplest example that we can't do with rosbuild so that need catkin?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-14**:
No, it's just another system that has other properties. You can build everything as before.